# are 'for' loops so memory hungry, compared with 'for of' in es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In Javascript, are **for** loops so memory intensive? I get a memory issue with when it should only be looping 36 times:

```
const suits = ['&hearts;', '&spades;', '&clubs;', '&diams;'],
      ranks = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'];
var cards = [];
for (let i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < ranks.length; i++) {
    var colour = 'black';
    if (suits[i] === '&hearts;' || suits[i] === '&diam;') {
      colour = 'red';
    }
    cards.push({
      suit : suits[i],
      rank : ranks[j],
      colour : colour,
      value : j+1
    });              
  }
}
console.log(cards);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xntL1ygj/

but this is fine:

```
const suits = ['&hearts;', '&spades;', '&clubs;', '&diams;'],
      ranks = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'];

let cards = [];

for (let suit of suits) {
  for (let rank of ranks) {
    var colour = 'black';
    if (suit === '&hearts;' || suit === '&diam;') {
      colour = 'red';
    }  
    cards.push({
      suit : suit,
      rank : rank,
      colour : colour,
      //value : j+1
    });              
  }
}
console.log(cards);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zfktu35t/

Comment: Both the inner and outer `for` loops have `i++`. The inner should be `j++`.

Comment: *"I get a memory issue"* What exactly is that issue and what did you do to find out about it?

Comment: `(let j = 0; j < ranks.length; i++)`

Comment: Thanks, all i needed was a second pair of eyes it seems. Duh-brain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const suits = ['&hearts;', '&spades;', '&clubs;', '&diams;'],
      ranks = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'];
var cards = [];
for (let i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
  // I fixed your bug below--it used to be i++, not j++
  for (let j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) { 
    var colour = 'black';
    if (suits[i] === '&hearts;' || suits[i] === '&diam;') {
      colour = 'red';
    }
    cards.push({
      suit : suits[i],
      rank : ranks[j],
      colour : colour,
      value : j+1
    });              
  }
}
console.log(cards);
```

Well, you see, when you

```
let j = 0; j < ranks.length; i++)
```

that loop runs forever, because `j` is always 0.  Funny, that.